# How to set resource-id/content-desc in flutter app for automation using Appium?

Tags: flutter, appium

To automate flutter app using Appium, we need to set the resource-id (for Android) and accessibility-Id/content-desc (for iOS) of any element/control in the flutter app. To get resource-id and accessibility-Id in the Appium tree view of flutter app, what should be done? Please help with possible solutions to achieve this.

Please refer below screenshot of Appium tree view which shows the missing resource-id.

[image]

Flutter version = 1.17.5

Please take a note that we have already tried "key" property of Widget for unique identification but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this [thread](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/12919) about Flutter support for Appium.

You can use [semanticLabel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Icon/semanticLabel.html) field, but it still feels like Flutter driver for Appium is far from stable state.